# CAPTCHA alternatives for dyslexic and dysgraphic users?

Tags: feature-request, captcha, accessibility

If a CAPTCHA system must be included, can it be ensured those of us with dyslexia & dysgraphia have alternative login authentications?

Both the audio and character based CAPTCHAs defeat me. When I was last challenged on  April 20th I was unable to pass.

Comment: Are you referring to the CAPTCHA with "I'm not a robot" checkmark? I see it regularly, when searching SE sites when I'm not logged in. Keeping the mouse pointer moving after clicking the checkmark suffices to pass, with no audio or character challenge.

Comment: @Norm true for search, but I think that on some cases they're still using the old one.

Comment: Excuse my curiosity, but how is it that you can form such a coherent question (grammatically correct, no spelling mistakes, capitalised acronyms, etc), but you can't pass a CAPTCHA even using the audio? (I'm not judging, just trying to understand your specific processing challenges).

Comment: Last times I got the CAPTCHA, they were the newer one with image recognition (sorry, couldn't find related meta post at the moment). But perhaps it's true that the old one is still used.

Comment: @lsugster Because i have a mixture of dysgraphia and dyslexia. I use spell checking with a lexicon of my common dyslexia induced errors. Reading obscured letters is a different skill, the dysgraphia makes it much harder to differentiate between an obscuring background and a distorted letter.  I have further problems with character orientation . and will often mistake numerals that share a common shape with a reversed letter.  I disambiguate with reader software if i cannot decipher a word,

Comment: I haven't been challenged by CAPTCHA since April, but haven't contributed to my normal stack exchanges since then either.

Comment: I was recently challenged on another site by a "chose the name of  the picture" capture, and was able to pass that. If the audio was unobscured, I could pass with greater ease an audio message to "select the ice cream cone image". Additionally, This would seem to offer  a greater deal of complexity to  the CAPTCHA  breakers